# What do I need to add to make my password change inside the database and allow that user to login with the new password

Tags: python, html, flask

This is the route that I am using to update the users pass. I did make a class called updateForm but it didn't seem to do anything.

Here is a github to my whole program so I am not posting the entire thing here, I feel like I'm close. Still new to flask.
https://github.com/FasterJake/Flask-Password-update

```
@app.route('/updatepass/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def updatepass(id):
    form = LoginForm()
    update_password = User.query.get(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        update_password = request.form['password']
        db.session.commit()

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            flash("User Updated Successfully!")
            return render_template("login.html",
                                   form=form,
                                   update_password=update_password,
                                   id=id)

        except:
            flash("Error!  Looks like there was a problem...try again!")
            return render_template("update.html",
                                   form=form,
                                   update_password=update_password,
                                   id=id)
    else:
        return render_template("update.html",
                               form=form,
                               update_password=update_password,
                               id=id)
```

This is the update html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Update Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Update Password</h1>

<form action="/updatepass/{{ update_password.id }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.password(class="form-control", value=update_password.password) }}

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a user modal, and you're using flask_wtf here is my suggestion:

```
@app.route('/updatepass/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def updatepass(id):
    form = UpdateForm() # flask_wtf form (class that inherits from FlaskForm)
    user = User.query.get(id) # you need to have a user modal
    if request.method == "POST":
        user.password = form.password.data  # use encryption here
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            flash("User Updated Successfully!")
            return render_template("login.html",
                                form=LoginForm(), # flask_wtf form
                                id=id)

        except: 
            flash("Error!  Looks like there was a problem...try again!")
            return render_template("update.html",
                                form=form,
                                id=id)
    else:
        return render_template("update.html",
                            form=form,
                            id=id)
```

Comment: I am using a user model but I haven't made an UpdateForm().

I did try something like this though:

class ChangePassword(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2,max=20)])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')

But it didnt do anything.